# How to cast a struct to a basic type, rather than the immediate type in Go?

Tags: go, struct, reflection, casting

I need to cast an interface of an unknown immediate type to a known basic type.

Example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    foo string
}

type B A

func main() {
    bS := B{foo: "foo"}
    bI := reflect.ValueOf(bS).Interface()
    fmt.Println(bI)

    aS := bI.(A)
    fmt.Println(aS)
}
```

When this code is run, it, understandably, panics with the following message

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is main.B, not main.A
```

In this example:

- type B is unknown to the code receiving the interface bI
- type B is
  guaranteed to be an alias to type A, which is known.

**Edit**: I can't use type aliasing here, because this means that type B would become just another way to write type A, so I'd lose all the custom methods I have defined on type B.

Comment: There is no way you can use one type in another type. But Please post the code where you re using one type and then wrapping the interface around the struct to achieve something.

Comment: This is all totally wrong. B is **not** an alias for A. Aliases are something completely different. B is a new named type whose underlying type is A. Type assertions are a third thing which turn interface types into what the interface wrapps. Redesign as nothing here seems to be sensible. One more: There are _not_ type casts in Go.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with `type aliasing` (released in Go1.9).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    foo string
}

type B = A

func main() {
    bS := B{foo: "foo"}
    bI := reflect.ValueOf(bS).Interface()
    fmt.Println(bI)

    aS := bI.(A)
    fmt.Println(aS)
}
```

N.B. `type B = A` makes is so that cast will work.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this solution doesn't work for my use-case, because type B would become just another way to write type A, so I'd lose all the custom methods I have defined on type B.

Answer (score 0):

the only way I know to go to the first struct is `aS := A(bI.(B))` is reversing the process. Hope it helps